# Slash commands only work on one Discord server? (discord.js v13)

Tags: discord.js

I noticed that slash commands only work on one Discord server: `bot.guilds.cache.get(<GUILD_ID>).commands.set(command.name, command)`.
Is there really no way to make the commands work right away on those servers where the bot already exists? Do I have to add IDs separately? I tried `bot.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.id).commands.set(command.name, command)`, but it gives an error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Client#application`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=application) to make a global command (works on all servers the bot is in with `application.commands` scope).

Use [`Guild#commands`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=commands) for guild specific commands

```js
bot.on("ready", () => {
  bot.application.commands.set([
    // Global command data
  ])
})
```

And for guild specific command:

```js
bot.guilds.cache.get("THE_GUILD_ID").commands.set(
  [
    // Guild command data
  ]
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, now slash commands work everywhere.

Comment: @user17481541 consider adding a checkmark to the answer if it helped

Comment: I was wrong, doesn't work. It works with `bot.guilds.cache.get().commans.set()`, but does not work with `bot.commands.set()`. With `bot.guilds.cache.get().commands.set()` slash commands appear, but with `bot.commands.set()` in servers slash commands not appear.

Comment: Use `bot.application.commands.set`

Comment: Slash commands were displayed, but when I entering command the bot thinks and does not output the command.

Comment: That should be a different question. This one was **setting** commands. You can make a new question asking about **replying to** commands